# Create/Apply grunge-vintage-worn- old-scratchy filters in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

Does anybody knows how to create/apply grunge or vintage-worn filters? I'm creating an iOS app to apply filters to photos, just for fun and to learn more about CIImage. Now, I'm using Core-Image to apply CIGaussianBlur, CIGloom, and the like through commands such as ciFilter.setValue(value, forKey:key) and corresponding commands.

So far, core image filters such as blur, color adjustment, sharpen , stylize work OK. But I'd like to learn how to apply one of those grunge, vintage-worn effects available in other photo editing apps, something like this:

[image]

[image]

Does anybody knows how to create/apply those kind of filters?
Thanks!!!

Comment: checkout this link  https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/10/20/ios-image-filters-in-swift/

Comment: Apple has an example named "Old Film Filter Recipe" in this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html

Comment: hi @jigneshVadadoriya. Unfortunately, that's a very basic tutorial and doesn't address the filter I'm looking for.

Comment: hi @Moritz, that page looks promising. I'll give it a try and see.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

(1) Use "canned" filters in a chain. If the output of one filter is the input of the next, code things that way. It won't waste any resources until you actually call for output.

(2) Write your own kernel code. It can be a *color* kernel that mutates a single pixel independently, a *warp* kernel that checks the values of a pixel and it's surrounding ones to generate the output pixel, or a *general* kernel that isn't optimized like the last two. Either way, you can use GLSL pretty much for the code (it's pretty much C language for the GPU).

Okay, there's a third option - a combination of the two above options. Also, in iOS 11 and above, you can write kernels using Metal 2.

Comment: I'm already working with "canned" filters (apply one filter to the output of another filter, and so on). The thing is that I don't know what filters will give me that worn-scratchy look to the pictures (see the images above). Is there a specific filter or set of filters I should apply? I already have mixed vintage, blur, and other but I cannot get that scratchy-old look.